# Print list of bad blocks in NAND flash from user space

Tags: linux, kernel, flash-memory, badblocks

Is there any user space tool that can retrieve and dump the list of bad blocks in a NAND flash device? I've checked the `mtdinfo` command line utility, and also searched `/proc` and `/sys`, but couldn't find anything.

I am looking for something suitable for use from a shell script.

I could parse `dmesg` as the kernel prints bad block information on init, but I am hoping there will be a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not been able to find any user space utility doing what I need. The closest I have found is the `nanddump` utility from [mtd-utils](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/), which can dump NAND contents, including bad blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem recently, and I wrote the C codes by referring open-source of mtd-utils, the core part is as follows,

```
    offset = 0;
    while (1) {
        int rc = ioctl(fd, MEMGETBADBLOCK, &offset);
        if (rc < 0) {
            perror("Failed to check bad block");
            close(fd);
            return 1;
        } else if (rc > 0) {
            // Block is bad, print the block information
            printf("Bad block at offset 0x%llx \n", offset);
        }

        offset += mtd_info.erasesize;
        if (offset > mtd_info.size)
            break;
    }
```